# Force update message for older versions of app

Tags: android, ios, app-store, auto-update

How do I force users with older versions to update if I didn't include a messaging interface?

Version 6 - 90% of users

Version 7 - 10% of users - no auto update as new permissions are needed

Version 7 solves some critical issues I need a way to present a modal for version 6 people that the app requires an update to function properly.

Is the only way to force version 6 to update is to upload a version 8 with the same permissions as version 6 and with a modal that links to the upgrade page?

Answer (score 0):

Use [appgrades.io](https://appgrades.io) to perform such task. Just integrate the sdk in your app and from the [Dashboard](https://dash.appgrades.io) you can restrict any version you want by designing a view or popup that will block navigation in your app unless the user updates the app.